# Java Swing checkboxes active

Tags: java, swing

I have a short question for you.
  I have 2 checkboxes and I want to:  when is the active one, the other   should    be off.
  Tks in advance!

Comment: You might want to use `JRadioButton` instead

Comment: You should use JRadioButtons if you want an either / or selection.

Comment: The design does not allow me... I need to do with checkbox

Comment: Visit duplicate question (you may need to refresh this page to see it). Accepted answer there works also for `JCheckBox`.

Comment: It's a different question!

Comment: and I expect another answer

Comment: @Norris29 This question is marked as a duplicate, so nobody can post an answer anymore. The only thing that is different from your question is the `JToggleButton` subclass being used. `ButtonGroup` will work for any `AbstractButton`s, so the answer would essentially be the same.

Comment: Ok . I appreciate your involvement!

Answer (score 0):

Please use JRadioButtons, that would fulfill your requirement.